# Posthoc test after Mixed Anova

Tags: time-series, mixed-model, anova, post-hoc

I would like to know what kind of posthoc test would be more adequate for time series analysis where after rejecting null hypotesis with Mixed Anova over multiple treatments and a control, i would like to pairwise compare each treatment vs control.
For example, if you measure your variable every second for each subject, and you reject the null hypotesis using mixed anova for an interval of 10 seconds (10 measurements per subject), how you do the posthoc comparison for the same time interval.
I read about do the test for each time bin, in this case, one posthoc test for each second. But i want to do it for the entire time interval.

Comment: See https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/bimj.200810425

Comment: I appreciate the help. But I couldnt find what im looking for.